# How to exclude not filled modelform fields from query

Tags: django, django-forms

I use a modelform and if user don't change some field default value then this field value interpreted as "null" in SQL query. What can I do for eliminate this value for query? I.e. don't use not filled field values.

===

I mean - form has a City field not filled by default, if user don't change this then in SQL query added "city=null", but I need to exclude conditions with null values.

Comment: Check it in `clean()`

Comment: Are you using `cleaned_data` ?

Comment: I would like to avoid processing in cleaned_data if it's possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I really understand the question:

Are you trying to allow empty form fields (you don't have to enter a city name)? Then you should just use `blank=True` for CharField or `blank=True, null=True` for e.g. DateField or ForeignKey.

Otherwise, there should be no empty form fields since if you change a model instance, django fills in the old value automatically.

Or do you want to enforce that the user enters a value? Then just don't state `blank=True` in your model attribute.